# How to count occurrences of text in a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, sort, uniq

I have a log file sorted by IP addresses,
I want to find the number of occurrences of each unique IP address. 
How can I do this with bash? Possibly listing the number of occurrences next to an ip, such as:

```
5.135.134.16 count: 5
13.57.220.172: count 30
18.206.226 count:2
```

and so on.

Here’s a sample of the log:

```
5.135.134.16 - - [23/Mar/2019:08:42:54 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
5.135.134.16 - - [23/Mar/2019:08:42:55 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
5.135.134.16 - - [23/Mar/2019:08:42:55 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3836 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
5.135.134.16 - - [23/Mar/2019:08:42:55 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
5.135.134.16 - - [23/Mar/2019:08:42:56 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 413 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:05 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:06 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3985 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:07 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:08 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3833 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:09 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:11 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3836 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:12 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:15 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3837 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 413 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
13.57.233.99 - - [23/Mar/2019:04:17:45 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
18.206.226.75 - - [23/Mar/2019:21:58:07 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "https://www.google.com/url?3a622303df89920683e4421b2cf28977" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
18.206.226.75 - - [23/Mar/2019:21:58:07 -0400] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3988 "https://www.google.com/url?3a622303df89920683e4421b2cf28977" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
18.213.10.181 - - [23/Mar/2019:14:45:42 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
18.213.10.181 - - [23/Mar/2019:14:45:42 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
18.213.10.181 - - [23/Mar/2019:14:45:42 -0400] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

Comment: With “bash”, do you mean the plain shell or the command line in general?

Comment: Do you have any database software available to use?

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/521891/counting-occurrences-in-first-column-of-a-file)

Comment: The log is from an appache2 server, not really a database. bash is what I would prefer, in a general use case. I see the python and perl solutions,  if they are good for someone else, that is great. 

the initial sorting was done with `sort -V` though I think that wasn't required. I sent the top 10 abusers of the login page to the system admin with recommendations for banning respective subnets. for example, One IP hit the login page over 9000 times. that IP, & its class D subnet is now blacklisted. I'm sure we could automate this, though that is a different question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `grep` and `uniq` for the list of addresses, loop over them and `grep` again for the count:

```
for i in $(<log grep -o '^[^ ]*' | uniq); do
  printf '%s count %d\n' "$i" $(<log grep -c "$i")
done
```

`grep -o '^[^ ]*'` outputs every character from the beginning (`^`) until the first space of each line, `uniq` removes repeated lines, thus leaving you with a list of IP addresses. Thanks to command substitution, the `for` loop loops over this list printing the currently processed IP followed by “ count ” and the count. The latter is computed by `grep -c`, which counts the number of lines with at least one match.

#### Example run

```
$ for i in $(<log grep -o '^[^ ]*'|uniq);do printf '%s count %d\n' "$i" $(<log grep -c "$i");done
5.135.134.16 count 5
13.57.220.172 count 9
13.57.233.99 count 1
18.206.226.75 count 2
18.213.10.181 count 3
```

Comment: This solution iterates over the input file repeatedly, once for each IP address, which will be very slow if the file is large. The other solutions using `uniq -c` or `awk` only need to read the file once,

Comment: @David this is true, but this would have been my first go at it as well, knowing that grep counts. Unless performance is measurably a problem... dont prematurely optimize?

Comment: I would not call it a premature optimization, given that the more efficient solution is also simpler, but to each their own.

Comment: By the way, why is it written as `<log grep ...` and not `grep ... log`?

Comment: @Santiago Because that’s better in many ways, [as Stéphane Chazelas explains here on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819).

Answer (score 40):

You can use `cut` and `uniq` tools:

```bsh
cut -d ' ' -f1 test.txt  | uniq -c
      5 5.135.134.16
      9 13.57.220.172
      1 13.57.233.99
      2 18.206.226.75
      3 18.213.10.181
```

Explanation :

- `cut -d ' ' -f1` : extract first field (ip address)
- `uniq -c` : report repeated lines and display the number of occurences

Comment: One could use `sed`, e.g. `sed -E 's/ *(\S*) *(\S*)/\2 count: \1/'` to get the output exactly like OP wanted.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the one by dessert needs to read the file repeatedly so is much slower. And you can easily use `sort file | cut ....`  in case you're not sure if the file is already sorted.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't specifically require the given output format, then I would recommend the already posted [`cut` + `uniq` based answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129523/178692)

If you *really* need the given output format, a single-pass way to do it in Awk would be

```
awk '{c[$1]++} END{for(i in c) print i, "count: " c[i]}' log
```

This is somewhat non-ideal when the input is already sorted since it unnecessarily stores all the IPs into memory - a better, though more complicated, way to do it in the pre-sorted case (more directly equivalent to `uniq -c`) would be:

```
awk '
  NR==1 {last=$1} 
  $1 != last {print last, "count: " c[last]; last = $1} 
  {c[$1]++} 
  END {print last, "count: " c[last]}
'
```

Ex.

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {last=$1} $1 != last {print last, "count: " c[last]; last = $1} {c[$1]++} END{print last, "count: " c[last]}' log
5.135.134.16 count: 5
13.57.220.172 count: 9
13.57.233.99 count: 1
18.206.226.75 count: 2
18.213.10.181 count: 3
```

Comment: it would be easy to change the  cut + uniq based answer with sed to appear in the demanded format.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider yes it would - I believe that was already pointed out in comments to that answer

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one possible solution:

```bsh
IN_FILE="file.log"
for IP in $(awk '{print $1}' "$IN_FILE" | sort -u)
do
    echo -en "${IP}\tcount: "
    grep -c "$IP" "$IN_FILE"
done
```

- replace `file.log` with the actual file name.
- the command substitution expression `$(awk '{print $1}' "$IN_FILE" | sort -u)` will provide a list of the unique values of the first column.
- then `grep -c` will count each of these values within the file.

---

```bsh
$ IN_FILE="file.log"; for IP in $(awk '{print $1}' "$IN_FILE" | sort -u); do echo -en "${IP}\tcount: "; grep -c "$IP" "$IN_FILE"; done
13.57.220.172   count: 9
13.57.233.99    count: 1
18.206.226.75   count: 2
18.213.10.181   count: 3
5.135.134.16    count: 5
```

Comment: Prefer `printf`...

Comment: This means you need to process the entire file multiple times. Once to get the list of IPs and then once more for each of the IPs you find.

Answer (score 5):

Some Perl:

```
$ perl -lae '$k{$F[0]}++; }{ print "$_ count: $k{$_}" for keys(%k)' log 
13.57.233.99 count: 1
18.206.226.75 count: 2
13.57.220.172 count: 9
5.135.134.16 count: 5
18.213.10.181 count: 3
```

This is the same idea as [Steeldriver's awk approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129526/85695), but in Perl. The `-a` causes perl to automatically split each input line into the array `@F`, whose first element (the IP) is `$F[0]`. So, `$k{$F[0]}++` will create the hash `%k`, whose keys are the IPs and whose values are the number of times each IP was seen. The `}{` is funky perlspeak for "do the rest at the very end, after processing all input". So, at the end, the script will iterate over the keys of the hash and print the current key (`$_`) along with its value (`$k{$_}`).

And, just so people don't think that perl forces you to write script that look like cryptic scribblings, this is the same thing in a less condensed form:

```
perl -e '
  while (my $line=<STDIN>){
    @fields = split(/ /, $line);
    $ip = $fields[0];
    $counts{$ip}++;
  }
  foreach $ip (keys(%counts)){
    print "$ip count: $counts{$ip}\n"
  }' < log
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is not what the OP want; however, if we know that the IP address length will be limited to 15 characters, a quicker way to display the counts with unique IPs from a huge log file can be achieved using `uniq` command alone:

```
$ uniq -w 15 -c log

5 5.135.134.16 - - [23/Mar/2019:08:42:54 -0400] ...
9 13.57.220.172 - - [23/Mar/2019:11:01:05 -0400] ...
1 13.57.233.99 - - [23/Mar/2019:04:17:45 -0400] ...
2 18.206.226.75 - - [23/Mar/2019:21:58:07 -0400] ...
3 18.213.10.181 - - [23/Mar/2019:14:45:42 -0400] ...
```

Options:

`-w N` compares no more than `N` characters in lines

`-c` will prefix lines by the number of occurrences

Alternatively, For exact formatted output I prefer `awk` (should also work for IPV6 addresses), ymmv.

```
$ awk 'NF { print $1 }' log | sort -h | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%s count: %d\n", $2,$1 }'

5.135.134.16 count: 5
13.57.220.172 count: 9
13.57.233.99 count: 1
18.206.226.75 count: 2
18.213.10.181 count: 3
```

Note that `uniq` won't detect repeated lines in the input file if they are not adjacent, so it may be necessary to `sort` the file.

Comment: Likely good enough in practice, but worth noting the corner cases. Only 6 *probably* constant characters after the IP ` - - [`.  But in theory the address could be up to 8 characters shorter than the maximum so a change of date could split the count for such an IP.  And as you hint, this won't work for IPv6.

Comment: I like it, I didnt know uniq could count!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Python 3:

```py
from collections import Counter

with open('sample.log') as file:
    counts = Counter(line.split()[0] for line in file)

for ip_address, count in counts.items():
    print('%-15s  count: %d' % (ip_address, count))
```

Output:

```
13.57.233.99     count: 1
18.213.10.181    count: 3
5.135.134.16     count: 5
18.206.226.75    count: 2
13.57.220.172    count: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f1 -d- my.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Explanation: Take the first field of my.log splitting on dashes `-` and sort it. `uniq` needs sorted input. `-c` tells it to count occurrences.